# C++: Copy constructor crashing

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having trouble coding Copy constructor for C++ HashTable.  Now below is the class structure

```
template <class TYPE>
class HashTable : public Table<TYPE>
{
    struct Record
    {
        TYPE data_;
        string key_;
        Record* Next;

        Record(const string& key, const TYPE& data)
        {
            key_ = key;
            data_ = data;
            Next = nullptr;
        }

        Record(const Record& a)  {
            if(!a.key_.empty()){

                if(a.Next == nullptr){
                    Next = nullptr;
                }
                else
                {
                    Record* temp = a.Next ;
                    Record *temp2 = Next;
                    while(temp != nullptr)
                    {
                        temp2 = temp ;
                        temp = temp->Next ;
                    }
                    temp2->Next = nullptr;
                }

                data_ = a.data_ ;
                key_ = a.data_ ;


            } // user-

        };

        int TableSize;
        Record** records;
    }
};
```

and below is the copy constructor 
template

```
HashTable<TYPE>::HashTable(const HashTable<TYPE>& other)
{
    records = new Record*[other.TableSize];
    TableSize = other.TableSize;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < other.TableSize; i++)
        records[i]= (new Record(*other.records[i]));    
}
```

I have also posted the code on ideone http://ideone.com/PocMTD. The code for copy constructor seems to be crashing. I don't see any memory leak that will cause the program to crash. I have tried memcopy, using the insert function and the all seems to fail.

Comment: Show how you initialize records array in the other constructor.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should also have a variable to iterate "this" object in the copy constructor of the Record. Right now you are only updating the next of the first record in what may be a list of records.

Comment: Give us enough code to replicate the crash.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I updated all the code on http://ideone.com/QIRv85. Now the class is hashtable and then default constructor, update , deconstructor is all there. I don't understand where I am making a silly mistake, I have used break points throughout the code and I find nothing.

Comment: That's an awful lot of code. Can you work on stripping it down to the minimum necessary to replicate the crash? You may even find the problem yourself in the process.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I cut down the code to minimum. these copy, operator= is where the problem lies. I should have posted the minimum code earlier my bad

Comment: @AndreyCheboksarov I posed the coded on  ideone.com/QIRv85. I doubt it's my default construct and etc because all the testing pass if I am working with the original hashtable object. the problem only starts when I make use of copy constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `int TableSize;` and `Record** records;` with `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Record>>`

In `Record`, change `Record* Next;` to `Record* Next=nullptr;`.

Stop calling `new`.

Include `HashTable(HashTable&&)=default;`.

```
HashTable<TYPE>::HashTable(const HashTable<TYPE>& other)
{
  records.reserve( other.records.size() );
  for (auto const& rec_in : other.records)
    records.emplace_back( new Record(*rec_in) ); // make_shared<Record> in C++14
}
```

Now we are no longer doing manual memory management.  So an entire set of worries is gone.

Next, look at that raw `Next` pointer.  It is bad news.  When you copy a `Record`, the `Next` pointer points into the *old* set of `Record` structures.

We can fix this in a few ways.  The slickest is to use an offset pointer.

```
template<class T>
struct offset_ptr {
  std::ptrdiff_t offset = std::numeric_limits<std::ptrdiff_t>::max();

  explicit operator bool()const {
    return offset!=std::numeric_limits<std::ptrdiff_t>::max();
  }

  T* get() const {
    return (T*)( offset+(char*)this );
  }
  T* operator->() const { return get(); }
  T& operator*() const { return *get(); }
  operator T*() const { return get(); }

  offset_ptr(std::nullptr_t):offset_ptr() {}

  explicit offset_ptr(T* p) {
    if (!p) return;
    offset = (char*)p-(char*)this;
    Assert(*this);
  }
  offset_ptr()=default;
  offset_ptr(offset_ptr const&)=default;
  offset_ptr& operator=(offset_ptr const&)=default;
  offset_ptr(offset_ptr&&)=default;
  offset_ptr& operator=(offset_ptr&&)=default;
};
```

which instead of storing a pointer by absolute location, stores an offset.

Now we do this:

```
template<class TYPE> struct Table{};

template <class TYPE>
class HashTable :public Table<TYPE>
{
public:
  struct Record
  {
    TYPE data_;
    std::string key_;
    offset_ptr<Record> Next;

    Record(const std::string& key, const TYPE& data)
    {
      key_ = key;
      data_ = data;
      Next = nullptr;
    }

    Record(const Record& a) 
    {
      if(!a.key_.empty())
      { 
        if(a.Next == nullptr)
        {
          Next = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
          auto temp = a.Next;
          while(temp != nullptr)
          {
            Next = temp;
            temp = temp->Next;
          }
        }

        data_ = a.data_;
        key_ = a.data_;
      } 
    }

  };
  std::vector<Record> records;
};
```

and no copy ctor is needed; the offset ptr knows the location of the other record as an offset within the records.  Data is stored by-value instead of by-reference.

Note that we have a `vector` of `Record`s, not pointers-to-`Record`s.  This is key for the `offset_ptr` to work.  Resizing isn't a problem, as the offsets remain the same.  Copying remains safe, as offsets on each side now refer to other elements within their vector.  Inserting/removing in the middle is dangerous, but simply nulling elements is not.

Note that buffers of size max `std::ptrdiff_t` or beyond are not supported by the above `offset_ptr`.  On a 64 bit system that is about 2 gigs; on a 64 bit system it is large.  (I don't use 0 for the null value, because if I did then an `offset_ptr<X>` as the first member of a `struct X` would nullify if I ever made it point to its enclosing `X`.)

`boost` also has a less bespoke `offset_ptr` type.  The implementation above is meant as a sketch of how easy it is, not a solid implementation.

Comment: as per the assignment specification I am restricted to using pointers. no vector :(

Comment: @Temptemp2 Write `my_vector<T>` which manages a size and a buffer of `T`, and supports `operator=(my_vector<T>&&)` and `operator=(my_vector<T> const&)` etc.  Splitting the responsibility of managing memory resources from business logic is one of the few ways to make memory handling reliable.  Doing it mixed in with business logic is, quite frankly, exceedingly expensive and unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

You do not show the complete code here (neither on ideone), but let me take a guess based on what I see.

- I assume that your `other` object, which you pass in the copy c'tor has a fully set up list of `Record`s.
- I further assume that your `HashTable` class has a destructor (not shown) which deletes all the linked `Record`s.
- Your copy constructor calls the copy c'tor of `Record`(for each entry in the array of pointers to `Record`). The `Record` coyp c'tor only makes a shallow copy, i.e. only the pointer to the next element is copied (it will still point to the next element of the copied Record from the `other` hash table.

Thus, when `other` and its copy are deleted (at the end of scope or program; not shown), you will have double deletion (crash).

*Fix*: Make sure that `Record` has correct copy constructor, copy assignment and destructor (maybe even move c'tor and move assignment) (rule of five).
The same applies for the `HashTable` class as well.

*Better fix*: Use `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: your assumption is right. yes I am gonna follow what you have said and try that approach. as for the code, I have uploaded all the files here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4Eho7p-TIQWWld5TkJwd3d5Unc?usp=sharing . unordered_map can't use it

Comment: it's so frustrating. I still haven't been able to resolve the problem. I am still getting error

Comment: I can only repeat what other commenters above have said before: Try to extract the _minimum_ (really!) example which exhibits the error (so far you have not done this). You will either find the error yourself by doing this or you can then post the code here. NB: By minimum example I understand something which does not exceed the size of a screen.